# Performance of absolute-positioned elements

Tags: html, css, performance

I appreciate that I could just "try it and see", but I'd prefer to err on the side of caution here and ask if anyone has prior experience with this matter, or knowledge that would allow an answer ;)

I'm working on a feature that will include many elements (around 800) in a canvas-like container. All of these are `<div>` elements with a `background-image`. They will be aligned to a grid.

I have some ideas for neat animations that would involve `transition`ing elements to their new positions when some of them are added or removed - this would involve `position:absolute` and setting `left` and `top` appropriately.

I'd like to know how well browsers would handle this kind of thing, or if I would be better off just using `display:inline-block` and letting them flow as they would - no neat transitions, though.

In short I'm just wondering if the use of `position:absolute`, ie. removing the elements from the document flow, would be too much for the browser to handle when updating, as opposed to simply allowing the elements to exist in the flow of the document.

Does that make sense? I feel like I'm wording this horribly XD

Comment: You can try `transform: translate` right?

Comment: @Mr_Green I could, but I'd prefer to avoid `transform` for functionality since I'd like to support IE8 for the time being.

Comment: I think floating should be appropriate here as to move those absolute elements browser has to carry out calculations on the back whereas in floats all you need to do is swap the `div` order

Answer (score 0):

If all of the elements will have the same height, then I'd just use display:inline-block or float:left, and they'll fit nicely together.

If the elements will have different heights, they will not perfectly "fall in line" when floated or displayed as inline-blocks.

For the latter, using a jquery plugin such as [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) would be a sensible solution. Masonry uses the absolute positioning your question refers to, and no, it is not too much for the browser "to handle."

You can, of course, still use Masonry if your divs will have the same height.

Without a script solution like Masonry, I doubt it'd be a good idea to use absolute positioning on 800 elements to achieve your desired result.